# Angular - UI Router - control access to state and redirect

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angularjs-rootscope

I develop a website with authentication process. User can be admin or not.
I write different components and differents states to route users.

I already control HTTP requests to handle anthentication process, but I want to force redirection when simple user try to go to a not Authorized Page page with typing adress.

### Example

He types admin url:

[image]

I want to redirect this user to the page where he's coming from, or force him to stay at the current page...

I try to do something like this:
[www.seanmarchetti.com/authentication_with_angularui_router.html](http://www.seanmarchetti.com/authentication_with_angularui_router.html)

But I have a different project structure

[image]

I control access to states in "admin", and I want to use `$state.go`, but to non-admin state..
I tried to use `toState` but didn't work (or I probably don't understand how use it properly)

Here is my code from `admin.router.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appModule.admin')
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/admin', '/admin/users');

    $stateProvider
      .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        redirectTo: 'admin.users',
        template: '<admin></admin>',
        needAdmin: true,
      })
      .state('admin.users', {
        url: '/users',
        template: '<users></users>',
        needAdmin: true,
      })
      .state('admin.apis', {
        url: '/apis',
        template: '<engines></engines>',
        needAdmin: true,
      })

  })
  .run(function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (toState.needAdmin && !Auth.isAdmin()) {
        console.log('fromstate', fromState);
        console.log('tostate', toState);
        $state.go('/*UNKNOWN  STATE FROM HERE*/');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```

Can anyone help me how can I redirect user properly to `.state unknown` from `admin` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just wrote anti-pattern for resolving states.

Please, use `resolve` property from `ui-router`: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve.

You should have a `function needAdmin() { return Promise (...) //or $q.deffer.promise }` that will `resolve(true)` if your check is passed (so state will be resolved) or `reject(); $state.go(...)` if your check failed.

`reject()` will automatically stop your state from resolving immediately (without any promises waiting to be resolved in memory to avoid memory leaks).

`resolve()` will just allow state to be resolved (accessed).

Simple example:

```js
// somewhere in your AuthFactory
AuthFactory.isAdmin () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  
  if (AuthFactory.isAdmin === true) {
    deffered.resolve(true);
  } else {
    deffered.reject('Not an admin');
    $state.go('...');
  }
  
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

```js
// in your configuration
$stateProvider
  .state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
  
    ...
  
    resolve: {
      checkAdminBeforeAccessing: function (AuthFactory) {
        return AuthFactory.isAdmin();
      }
    }
  })
  .state('anotherStateNeedAdmin', {
    url: '/another',
  
    ...
  
    resolve: {
      checkAdminBeforeAccessing: function (AuthFactory) {
        return AuthFactory.isAdmin();
      }
    }
```